# TabHost disappears after locking the phone and reopening it:

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I have a weird issue with my `TabHost` in my `FragmentActivity` that contains a `ViewPager`.

The problem is that when I close my phone (press the power button) while I use my application, and then I turn back the phone and my application gets reopened, at this point my `TabHost` is missing. So the closing of my phone is causes the `TabHost` to disappear.

My guess would be that I need to save my `tabHost` state in the `saveInstanceState` object, and restore it in `onResume` I only have no idea how it's done. here is my code for the `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener 
{
static final String TAG = TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo;
public ViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private TextView tvReportName, tvTabTitle;
private Button bBackToParameters;
private Dialog progressDialog;
private SGRaportManagerAppObj application;
private int numberOfTabs = 0;
private Display display;
public static final int POPUP_MARGIN = 6;
LeftSideMenu leftSideMenu;

public void NotifyTabActivityViewPagerAdapter()
{
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ViewPagerAdapter getTabActivityViewPagerAdapter()
{
    return mPagerAdapter;
}

public ViewPager getTabActivityViewPager()
{
    return mViewPager;
}

public void setCurrentTabTitle (String title)
{
    tvTabTitle.setText(title);
    Log.d(TAG, "set tab title from activity: "+title);
}


/**
* Maintains extrinsic info of a tab's construct
*/
private class TabInfo 
{
    private String tag;
    private Class<?> clss;
    private Bundle args;
    private Fragment fragment;

    TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) 
    {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.clss = clazz;
        this.args = args;
    }
}

/**
 * A simple factory that returns dummy views to the Tabhost
 */
class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
*/
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    application = SGRaportManagerAppObj.getInstance();
    display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    // Inflate the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.tabs_screen_activity_layout);
    tvTabTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTabName);
    tvReportName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvReportName);
    tvReportName.setText(application.currentReport.getName()+ " - ");
    bBackToParameters = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBackToParameters);
    leftSideMenu = (LeftSideMenu) findViewById(R.id.leftSideMenu);
    applyOnClickListenerToLeftSideMenu();

    findViewById(R.id.showLeftMenuButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {               
            Display d = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            int width = d.getWidth();

            View panel = findViewById(R.id.leftSideMenu);
            View appPanel = findViewById(R.id.appLayout);
            if (panel.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                appPanel.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                applyOnClickListenerToLeftSideMenu();
            }else{
                ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.showLeftMenuButton);
                button.setChecked(false);
                panel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    // Initialise the TabHost
    progressDialog = DialogUtils.createProgressDialog(this, this.getString(R.string.populating_view_pager));
    progressDialog.show();

    if (SGRaportManagerAppObj.getInstance().parametersRepository.getParametersRepository().size() == 0)
    {
        bBackToParameters.setText(R.string.back_to_report_list);
    }
    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }
    // Intialise ViewPager
    this.intialiseViewPager();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

 /** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Initialise ViewPager
 */
public void intialiseViewPager() 
{

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

  // TabInfo tabInfo = null;

    if (application.getCurrentDataSource().equals(DataSource.SSRS))
    {
        numberOfTabs = application.currentReport.getTabsList().size();
    }
    else if (application.getCurrentDataSource().equals(DataSource.SGRDL))
    {
        numberOfTabs = application.currentReport.getODTabsList().size();
        Log.d(TAG, "CURRENT REPORT FROM VIEW PAGER: "+ application.currentReport.toString());
    }   

    Log.d(TAG,"Current Tabs number from TabsViewPager activity: " +numberOfTabs);

    if (application.getCurrentDataSource().equals(DataSource.SSRS))
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++)     
         {
            Tab tempTab = application.currentReport.getTabsList().get(i);
            if (tempTab.getTabTemplateId() == 7)
            {
                GridFragment gridFragment = new GridFragment(tempTab);
                fragments.add(gridFragment);
            }
            else  if (tempTab.getTabTemplateId() == 8)
            {
                NewChartFragment chartFragment = new NewChartFragment(tempTab, this);
                fragments.add(chartFragment);
            }
         }
    }
    else if (application.getCurrentDataSource().equals(DataSource.SGRDL))
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++)     
         {
            ODTab tempTab = application.currentReport.getODTabsList().get(i);
            if (tempTab.getTabType().equals(ODGrid.XML_GRID_ELEMENT))
            {
                GridFragment gridFragment = GridFragment.newInstance(tempTab.getTabId());
                fragments.add(gridFragment);
            }
            else  if (tempTab.getTabType().equals(ODChart.XML_CHART_ELEMENT))
            {
                NewChartFragment chartFragment = NewChartFragment.newInstance(tempTab.getTabId());
                fragments.add(chartFragment);
            }
         }
    }   

    Log.d(TAG, "Current report fragments set to adapter: "+fragments.toString());
   /*
    if (this.mPagerAdapter == null)
    {
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    }
    else
    {
        this.mPagerAdapter.removeAllFragments();
        this.mPagerAdapter.addFragmentsListToAdapter(fragments);
    }
    */
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
//    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(null);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter initialized!");
}

/**
 * Initialise the Tab Host
 */
public void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    /*
    //new edit
    if (mTabHost.getChildCount() > 0)
    {
        mTabHost.removeAllViews();
    }
    */

    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.TabInfo>();
    if (args != null)
    {}
    else
    {
        if (application.getCurrentDataSource().equals(DataSource.SSRS))
        {
            int numberOfTabs = application.currentReport.getTabsList().size();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++)      
            {
                Tab tempTab = application.currentReport.getTabsList().get(i);
                if (tempTab.getTabTemplateId() == 7)
                {
                    //GridFragment gridFragment = new GridFragment(tempTab);
                    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)).setIndicator("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab "+String.valueOf(i), GridFragment.class, args)));
                    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
                }
                else  if (tempTab.getTabTemplateId() == 8)
                {
                    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)).setIndicator("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab "+String.valueOf(i), NewChartFragment.class, args)));
                    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (application.getCurrentDataSource().equals(DataSource.SGRDL))
        {
            int numberOfTabs = application.currentReport.getODTabsList().size();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++)      
            {
                ODTab tempTab = application.currentReport.getODTabsList().get(i);
            //  Log.d(TAG,"Crashed Tab type: "+ tempTab.getTabType());
                if (tempTab.getTabType().equals(ODGrid.XML_GRID_ELEMENT))
                {
                    //GridFragment gridFragment = new GridFragment(tempTab);
                    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)).setIndicator("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab "+String.valueOf(i), GridFragment.class, args)));
                    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
                }
                else  if (tempTab.getTabType().equals(ODChart.XML_CHART_ELEMENT))
                {
                    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)).setIndicator("Tab "+String.valueOf(i)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab "+String.valueOf(i), NewChartFragment.class, args)));
                    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Default to first tab
    //this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * Add Tab content to the Tabhost
 * @param activity
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 * @param clss
 * @param args
 */
private static void AddTab(TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) 
{
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec       
    ImageView indicator = new ImageView(activity.getBaseContext());
    indicator.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_select_icon_selector);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    indicator.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tabSpec.setIndicator(indicator); 
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}


/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

How would one save the state of the `TabHost` and restore it in `onResume`?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does the `TabHost` reappear at a later point? have you tested this on various android versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When putting the phone to sleep `onPause` and `onStop` get called but onDestroy doesn't so that onCreate doesn't get called when turning the phone back on.

`onRestart`, `onStart` and `onResume` do get called (checked on Nexus 7 by modifying the Activity Lifecycle training app to add Log messages in all lifecycle methods) so try to move as much code in `initialiseTabHost` as you can from `onCreate` to `onStart`, leaving only the minimum necessary in `onCreate`, or leave it there and add the relevant part of it to `onRestart`.

**Update (Emil Adz):**
As you suggested I added the `onResume` method and changed it as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mTabHost == null)
    {
        this.initialiseTabHost(null);
    }
}
```

From my check it looks as if it solved my problem, Thank you very much.

**Edit (Julien):** Looking at your `onResume` I am wondering why mTabHost is `null`. I expected that it didn't appear due to some initialisation that needed to be done after an `onStop` but I didn't expect it to be totally gone.

Ideally we should find out why mTabHost ends up being `null` and the problem is that I cannot reproduce the bug. If I gut your code of every class I do not have access to I get the following activity which displays 3 tabs and still displays them when I put the device to sleep andwake it up:

```
package com.example.tabhost;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener 
{
    static final String TAG = TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TabHost mTabHost;  // TabHost? Why not a FragmentTabHost?
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TextView tvTabTitle;
    private Display display;
    public static final int POPUP_MARGIN = 6;

    public void NotifyTabActivityViewPagerAdapter() {}

    public boolean getTabActivityViewPagerAdapter()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public ViewPager getTabActivityViewPager()
    {
        return mViewPager;
    }

    public void setCurrentTabTitle (String title)
    {
        tvTabTitle.setText(title);
        Log.d(TAG, "set tab title from activity: "+title);
    }

    private class TabInfo 
    {
        private String tag;
        private Class<?> clss;
        private Bundle args;
        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) 
        {
            this.tag = tag;
            this.clss = clazz;
            this.args = args;
        }
    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        public TabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        // Inflate the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialise the TabHost
        this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        /*
         * Why not use a FragmentTabHost and  setup (Context context, FragmentManager manager, int containerId)
         * see: http://getquery.com/android-fragment-tab-example/
         */
        mTabHost.setup();  


        int numberOfTabs = 3;//application.currentReport.getTabsList().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTabs; i++)
        {
            String str = "Tab " + String.valueOf(i);

            TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec(str).setIndicator(str), null);
        }
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    private static void AddTab(TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) 
    {
        // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec       
        ImageView indicator = new ImageView(activity.getBaseContext());
        indicator.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        indicator.setLayoutParams(lp);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(indicator); 
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("onStart", "mTabHost = " + mTabHost);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
        int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```

I used this layout (from http://getquery.com/android-fragment-tab-example/):

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Does that code work on your device or do your tabs still disappear?

Comment: I will try that and let you know what is the result, thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: Could you just tell me why in the end you said that maybe it's better to move to onRestart and no onResume? what is the differences between the two?

Comment: I would avoid `onResume` because when `onResume` is called the activity is already visible and you want to add your `TabHost` before that otherwise your activity shows without it then adds it (it might not be visible due to the speed of adding it but it's better not to risk it unless you have to).

Comment: So onRestart runs before onResume and before the activity is visible? should I move this functionality to onRestart?

Comment: "So onRestart runs before onResume" yes, but it only runs if the activity wasn't destroyed. "should I move this functionality to onRestart?" It's unlikely to make any visible difference but it would be conceptually cleaner.

Comment: Actually, I need to change something. When playing with TabHost on my  phone only `onPause` and `onResume` got called, whereas on the Nexus 7 `onStop` and `onStart` (as well as `onRestart`) got called too. As it looks like `on[Re]Start` is not guaranteed to be called when waking a device then putting the code in onResume seems safer (though the best would be to find out why the TabHost gets lost in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for this comment, then I leave my TabHost initialization in onResume, while i can't find the reason for it's disappearance.